# Usage of one, one's, oneself, one's own

Tags: usage, pronouns

I'm not sure but I think "one" refers to the people in general or anyone. I've found the following sentences where **One** has been used :

> 1. One must treat other as one expect to be treated.
> 2. One should take care of one's health.
> 3. One should do one's best at all times.

1. What **one** actually refers to in above sentences?
2. Can I use- **one's own health** and **his own health** in the second sentence?
3. Can I say "One should take care of **oneself** or **himself**" ? Both correct?

Comment: These days, English speakers generally use "you" and "your" instead of "one" and "one's", and although the latter usage is understood, some people might consider it to be "posh".

Comment: "One" is third-person singular, like *he* or *she*, so any time you use a verb with it, it should be the appropriate third-person singular form: "...as one **expects** to be treated", just like it would be for "he *expects*".

Answer (score 1):

1. "one" refers to a general person.
2. Yes, generally you can use "one's own" instead of "one's". Note, that "his own" excludes "her own" which is also covered by "one's own" so in general you cannot just use "his own" in place of "one's own".
3. "Oneself or himself" make no sense, because "himself" is already covered by "oneself". "Herself or himself" instead could be an option.

Comment: Are the following sentences correct grammatically ?

1. One should take care of oneself.
2. One should take care of himself.
3. One should take care of themselves.
4. One should take care oneself.
5. One should take care of himself.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes, but excludes women. 3. No. 4. Yes, but the meaning is not what you think. 5. Is the same as 2.

Comment: 6. One should take care of one's own health.

Comment: You have already asked about that. It's 2 in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

'One' is used as a gender-neutral third person singular to refer to an unknown person(as opposed to eg animals).  It is not specified whether the person referred to is male or female.  It is considered quite formal these days, and tends to be replaced by either 'you' or 'they'.

He/him/himself could replace one/one's/oneself grammatically, but from a usage point of view you might have changed a gender neutral sentence into a sentence about a man.  Using both 'one' and 'him' to refer to the same person is incorrect: use of 'him' implies you know its a man, whereas use of 'one' implies it could be a woman.

Answer (score 1):

["One" is used as a pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)), in place of "a person".  While it's true (as Mick says) that it's not as commonly used these days I think your English is advanced enough you should become familiar with it.  It can be a useful *genderless* pronoun if you don't want to pick between male or female.

"One" can be used in place of "you", for example:

> One should take care not to use "one" too frequently, [lest](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/lest) one sound [pompous](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/pompous).

It can be a little tricky to use "one" in a sentence.  It can seem overly formal to use "one" too many times in a sentence, but at the same time it can be awkward to switch between pronouns, especially if you're trying to avoid gender.  Example:

> "One needs to provide food for oneself and one's family". (formal)
>
> "One needs to provide food for himself and his family." (less formal, but requires you to pick between the male and female pronouns)

"One" is a third-person pronoun, so it can be useful if you want to avoid saying something that could be interpreted as directed at the listener.

> "You need to provide food for yourself and your family" (fine, but the listener might think you're talking specifically about *them*)

"One" also doesn't work well as the object of a sentence:

> "I give one an apple" (formal, but sounds very awkward)

As you noticed, you can use the possessive "one's" and the reflexive "oneself".  As before, these are formal and should be used carefully, once you understand the nuance.

Lastly, "one" is much more common in writing than when speaking, and you should probably avoid it in conversation as it can sound awkwardly formal.

[More information on using "one"](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/one-versus-you)

Comment: Are the following sentences correct grammatically ?

1. One should take care of oneself.
2. One should take care of himself.
3. One should take care of themselves.
4. One should take care oneself.
5. One should take care of himself.

Comment: 6. One should take care of one's own healt.

Comment: "One" is singular third person, so "one should take care of *themselves*" is not *strictly speaking* grammatically correct.  However it has become acceptable to use "they/them/their/themselves" as a third-person gender-neutral singular, so it's actually ok in most contexts.   The rest of your sentences are correct.

Comment: what do you think about my 1 and 2 sentence, oneself and himself ? Does "Himself" excludes women if we use it like in that sentence?

Comment: I'm really confused weather to use oneself or himself

Comment: @yubrajsharma the gender-bias issue merits its own question.  In a nutshell, it's become problematic to use "he" when you mean "he or she".  "Himself" doesn't exclude women, but it's not a good practice.  See [this](http://www.proedit.com/tips-for-avoiding-gender-bias-in-writing/) for more information.

Comment: @yubrajsharma you're not the only one who is confused.  It's a problem for any English writer.  It's too bad "one" feels so formal and archaic, because it could be very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. what do you mean by picking between man and women pronouns in your third sentence **One needs to provide food for himself and his family." (less formal, but requires you to pick between the male and female pronouns)**

Is this sentence only talking about **male** ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma No, I'm talking about "gender bias", the subject of that article I linked to in my previous comment:  [Tips for Avoiding Gender Bias in Writing](http://www.proedit.com/tips-for-avoiding-gender-bias-in-writing/).  In many situations it's not acceptable to use male pronouns as a generic pronoun that can mean both male and female.  The article discusses various techniques to avoid having to use a gendered pronoun.  But as I said you really should ask this as a separate question, the answers might be interesting.